# Unattended downloading of files from Sharepoint Online

Tags: document-library, powershell, sharepoint-online

I want all users on my SharePoint Online 2013 (plan 2) to be able to 'drop' files in a SharePoint folder, after which an unattended process downloads these files onto a local folder on a Windows Server 2012 and then deletes them from SPO.

The only way I can think of of doing this is through a scheduled PowerShell script. So I am looking for a script that can move all files in a specific folder on SharePoint Online 2013 to a local folder. After downloading I want these files removed from SharePoint. This whole process should be able to run unattended.

Is this the right way to go? Who can point me towards examples / documentation?

Answer (score 2):

This can be converted to [PowerShell](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html), or be executed as C#, however you wish:

```
using ( var ctx = new ClientContext( "siteUrl" ) )
{
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials( userName, secureStringPassword );
    var query = new CamlQuery
                {
                    ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>" +
                              "<Query>" +
                              "<Where>" +
                              "<Eq>" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/>" +
                              "<Value Type='Int'>0</Value>" +
                              "</Eq>" +
                              "</Where>" +
                              "</Query>" +
                              "</View>"
                };
    var web = ctx.Web;
    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle( library);
    var items = list.GetItems( query );
    ctx.Load( items, collection => collection.Include( i => i.File.ServerRelativeUrl, i => i.File.Name ) );
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    if ( items != null )
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            using ( var fi = File.OpenBinaryDirect( ctx, item.File.ServerRelativeUrl ) )
            {
                FileStream fileStream;
                using ( fileStream = new FileStream( @"fileDestination", FileMode.Create ) )
                {
                    if ( fi != null ) fi.Stream.CopyTo( fileStream );
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Be aware of timeouts.  If the library contains several files, you may get a timeout error.  You can try setting the `ClientContext.RequestTimeout`, but that never seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a right way to go.

In order to download files from SharePoint you could utilize [File.OpenBinaryDirect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarydirect%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

### Example

The below example demonstrates how to download files from a specific folder

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 



Function Download-File(){
param(
   $listItem = $(throw “Please provide a List Item”),
   $downloadPath = $(throw “Please specify a Path”)
)

  $context = $listItem.Context 
  $fileUrl = $listItem["FileRef"]
  $fi = new-object System.IO.FileInfo($listItem["FileRef"])
  $fileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($context, $fileUrl);
  try{
     $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($downloadPath,$fi.Name)
     $fileStream = [System.IO.File]::Create($fileName)           
     $fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($fileStream)
  }
  finally {
     $fileStream.Dispose()
  }
}



$Url = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/"
$UserName = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = "password"
$listTitle = "Documents"
$folder = "/Shared Documents/Archive"



if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Password)) {
   $SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password" -AsSecureString 
}
else {
   $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
}


$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$SecurePassword)
$ctx.credentials = $credentials

#Retive items from a specific folder
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
$query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
$query.FolderServerRelativeUrl=$folder;
$items = $list.GetItems($query)
$ctx.Load($items)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()


#Download file(s)
foreach ($item in $items){

  if($item.FileSystemObjectType -ne [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileSystemObjectType ]::File) {
     continue
  } 
  Download-File $item "C:\Temp\Archive"


  #Delete Item
  $item.DeleteObject()
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
```